# issue when Upgrading to jQuery 1.5.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

the `delete` link don't work when I upgrading from jquery 1.5 to jquery 1.5.1:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EfsGN/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug with the [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone) method that was [introduced in jQuery 1.5](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8123), and [fixed in 1.5.1](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/375b78783825b9adab7a01541faf99f98ef7ecbd/).

The default behaviour with `clone()` should be to **not** copy the events and data of the cloned element, however this was not the case with 1.5 (where the default behaviour **was** to copy the events).

To fix your code, change:

```
$('#add-input').click(function() {
    main.append(clonedField.clone());
    return false;
});
```

to

```
$('#add-input').click(function() {
    main.append(clonedField.clone(true));
    return false;
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfsGN/7/

Comment: Just thank you for the answer. very useful. I will give 100+ if I could.